# HashCode giving negative values

Tags: java, hashcode, negative-number

I am converting the incoming string into hash code by doing the following function but some of the values are negative. I don't think hash values should be negative. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
int combine = (srcadd + dstadd + sourceport + destinationport + protocol).hashCode();
System.out.println(combine);
```

Comment: Why can't hash codes be negative? AFAIK, the only requirement to them is to be equal for equal objects..

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> I don't think hash values should be negative.

Why not? It's entirely valid to have negative hash codes. Most ways of coming up with a hash code naturally end up with negative values, and anything dealing with them should take account of this. However, I'd consider a different approach to coming up with your hash codes, e.g.

```
int hash = 17;
hash = hash * 31 + srcadd.hashCode();
hash = hash * 31 + dstadd.hashCode();
hash = hash * 31 + sourceport; // I'm assuming this is an int...
hash = hash * 31 + destinationport; // ditto
hash = hash * 31 + protocol.hashCode();
return hash;
```

It's not clear what the types of these expressions are, but I'm guessing you're ending up taking the hash code of a string... a string that you don't really need to create in the first place. While there are better approaches for getting hash codes for known domains, the above approach works well as a general-purpose hash generation technique.

Note that it would also help the readability of your code if you avoided abbreviations, and used camel casing, e.g. `sourceAddress` instead of `srcadd`.

Comment: Actually it was written at some forum that "hashCode is a way of computing a small (32-bit) digest numeric key from a long String ".So, i though its range is 2^32 and that is from 0 to 2^32

Comment: @Zara: But `int` doesn't support numbers greater than 2^31 - 1... it *is* a 32-bit value, but in a signed range.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you elaborate why you set hash = 17 and you multiple by 31? I'm a little lost with this detail.

Comment: @bsheps: To be honest they're numbers copied from Josh Bloch. There are whole threads elsewhere about the choice of numbers for this approach.

Answer (score 45):

sometimes the `hashcode` calculation itself goes beyond the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, i.e `2147483647`. what happens then is that we get a negative integer after the `overflow`. **Negative hashcode is perfectly valid!**

Answer (score 26):

It is perfectly legal to have negative **hash codes**, and if you are looking for ***hash values*** as used in hash-based collections you can use `Math.abs(hash)`. This can also give you negative numbers when hash is bigger than 2^31, and the best way would be to use a shift mask `(key.hashCode() & 0x7fffffff) % M`, where M is the table size.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just use Math.abs(hash).  It's my understanding that Math.abs() will only return negative for int.MIN_VALUE.  If hash = key.hashCode() % M then the only way to end up with hash == int.MIN_VALUE is if M > int.MAX_VALUE, in which case you'd need to be using longs to index the table anyway.

Comment: By "bigger than 2^31", this answer really means "more than 31 binary digits", not a larger *integer* than 2^31.  Why `(key.hashCode() & 0x7fffffff)`?  Because it is a simple 1-step binary operation on the result of `hashCode()` that should (or could) execute faster than `Math.abs()`.