# HashCode and Equals method in Java object

Tags: java

Why always override hashcode() if overriding equals()?
Give me an example..

Comment: [Click me gently](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html).

Comment: They are not interchangeable, which renders your question senseless. It's like asking "what is the difference between `String` and a normal `List`"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `equals()` and `hashcode()` method in Object class. There is no normal or not normal version of methods.

If you are using any hash related data structure like HashMap or HashSet then you need to override hashcode() method. However in general it is a good practice to override hashcode() whenever you override equals().