# Android ArrayList: check an element exists of another ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two `ArrayList`.

```
private ArrayList<Friend> friendsList = new ArrayList<Friend>();
private ArrayList<Friend> myFriendsList = new ArrayList<Friend>();
```

First one contains all `Friend` of database. Second one contains only user `Friend`. In my search option(`SearchManager`) i've a `ListView` contains searched friends of `friendsList`. When i select a `Friend` of `ListView`, i want to check if the `Friend` exists in `myFriendsList`. I used following code

```
friendListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    handelListItemClick(adapter.getItem(position));
                }
            });


    private void handelListItemClick(Friend friend) {

    for(Friend fr: myFriendsList){
        Log.v("Check User Name:", fr.getName());
    }
    if (myFriendsList.contains(friend)) {works with matched friend}
```

But it can't check the selected `Friend` in `myFriendsList`. In `LogCat` it show `myFriendsList` information. Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Here is my `Friend` class

```
public class Friend {

private String id, name, thumbnailUrl;

public Friend() {
}

public Friend(String name, String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.name = name;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}

public Friend(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    this.id = id; 
}

public String getID(){
    return id;
}

public void setID(String id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}
```

}

Comment: show the implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` method of the `Friend` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use methods to find and search like `contains` your custom class MUST implement correctly the `hasCode` and `equals` methods.

Here is the [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28) about the implementing `hasCode` and [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) about implementing `equals`. It is Java Best Practises website that I like very much and from where I've learned about it.

Comment: would you please explain me `hasCode` and `equals` methods

Comment: check out links as what Shubhang proposed is my answer with code however his code is incorrect implementation.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela Hi Lucasz! can you tell me precisely what is incorrect in my code implementation ?

Comment: Sure, two objects are equal when they both have the same information, assuming that id is some sort of unique identifier is misleading and your implementation should employ id, name and image url.

Answer (score 0):

equals() is used in most collections to determine if a collection contains a given element

hashCode() of this object is calculated and used to determine where to search for the object in the hash tables.

For more information on either of these topics visit [oracle webiste](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) or take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027845)

If You could decide that two Friend objects are equal to each other if just their id's are equal.

So , In your Friend Class include

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Friend)) return false;

    Friend friend = (Friend) o;

    if (!id.equals(friend.id)) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
}
```

Now just do,

```
private void handelListItemClick(Friend friend) {
    if (myFriendsList.contains(friend)) {works with matched friend}
}
```

**Edit**

You can take a look at [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html) tutorial to learn more about the topic