# The pulldown list get using ZoneId is too long, how to simplify the list?

Tags: java, timezone, java-time

Using Spring `ZoneId`, the code is:

```
 private static Map<String, String> getAllZoneIds() {
    final List<String> zoneList = new ArrayList<>(ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds());
    final Map<String, String> zones = new HashMap<>();

    final LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();

    for (final String zoneId : zoneList) {

        final ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(zoneId);
        final ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
        final ZoneOffset zos = zdt.getOffset();

        //replace Z to +00:00
        final String offset = zos.getId().replaceAll("Z", "+00:00");

        zones.put(zone.toString(), offset);

    }

    final Map<String, String> sortZones = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    zones.entrySet().stream().sorted((left, right) -> {
        final String leftValue = left.getValue();
        final String leftKey = left.getKey();
        final String rightValue = right.getValue();
        final String rightKey = right.getKey();

        if (leftValue.equalsIgnoreCase(rightValue)) {
            return leftKey.compareTo(rightKey);
        } else {
            if (leftValue.charAt(0) == '+' &&  leftValue.charAt(0) == rightValue.charAt(0)) {
                return leftValue.compareTo(rightValue);
            } else {
                return rightValue.compareTo(leftValue);
            }
        }
    }).forEachOrdered(e -> {
        sortZones.put(e.getKey(), e.getKey() + " (UTC" + e.getValue() + ")");
    });
    System.out.println(sortZones);
    return sortZones;
}
```

Output is:

```
....
Antarctica/Casey->Antarctica/Casey (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Brunei->Asia/Brunei (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Chongqing->Asia/Chongqing (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Chungking->Asia/Chungking (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Harbin->Asia/Harbin (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Hong_Kong->Asia/Hong_Kong (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Hovd->Asia/Hovd (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Irkutsk->Asia/Irkutsk (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Kuala_Lumpur->Asia/Kuala_Lumpur (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Kuching->Asia/Kuching (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Macao->Asia/Macao (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Macau->Asia/Macau (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Makassar->Asia/Makassar (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Manila->Asia/Manila (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Shanghai->Asia/Shanghai (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Singapore->Asia/Singapore (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Taipei->Asia/Taipei (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Ujung_Pandang->Asia/Ujung_Pandang (UTC+08:00)
Australia/Perth->Australia/Perth (UTC+08:00)
Australia/West->Australia/West (UTC+08:00)
Etc/GMT-8->Etc/GMT-8 (UTC+08:00)
Hongkong->Hongkong (UTC+08:00)
PRC->PRC (UTC+08:00)
Singapore->Singapore (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Pyongyang->Asia/Pyongyang (UTC+08:30)
....
```

But the list is too long, it contains more than 500 options, and it is full of repetition. For example, ChongQing exists twice:

```
Asia/Chongqing->Asia/Chongqing (UTC+08:00)
Asia/Chungking->Asia/Chungking (UTC+08:00)
```

How to use this to be a shorter list?

Comment: and so is Singapore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some zones appear twice due to the [backward file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/backward): this file maps timezones names that were changed, but the old names were kept as synonyms, probably due to retrocompatibility reasons. If you take a look at the file, you'll find these entries:

```
Link    Asia/Shanghai       Asia/Chongqing
Link    Asia/Shanghai       Asia/Chungking
```

Which means that `Asia/Shanghai` is the current timezone name for `Asia/Chungking` and `Asia/Chongqing` timezones. One way to check if two zones are the same is to compare their respective `ZoneRules`:

```
ZoneId chungking = ZoneId.of("Asia/Chungking");
ZoneId chongqing = ZoneId.of("Asia/Chongqing");
ZoneId shanghai = ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai");
System.out.println(chungking.getRules().equals(chongqing.getRules()));
System.out.println(chungking.getRules().equals(shanghai.getRules()));
```

Both comparisons print `true`, which means all the `ZoneId` objects above represent the same timezone. Unfortunately, comparing the `ZoneId` objects directly doesn' work, only by comparing the `ZoneRules` we can know if two zones are the same.

So one way to reduce your list is to ignore the synonyms. If two or more zones have the same `ZoneRules`, you can consider just one of them to be in the list.

For that, you could create an auxiliary class that wraps a `ZoneId`, and has an `equals` method that compares the `ZoneRules` (and also a `hashcode` method, as it's a [good practice to properly implement both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java)).

```
public class UniqueZone {

    private ZoneId zone;

    public UniqueZone(ZoneId zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    public ZoneId getZone() {
        return zone;
    }

    // hashcode and equals use the ZoneRules
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((zone == null) ? 0 : zone.getRules().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof UniqueZone))
            return false;
        UniqueZone other = (UniqueZone) obj;
        if (zone == null) {
            if (other.zone != null)
                return false;
        // two zones are equal if the ZoneRules are the same
        } else if (!zone.getRules().equals(other.zone.getRules()))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then I create a `Set` of `UniqueZone` instances, using all the zone IDs available:

```
Set<UniqueZone> uniqueZones = ZoneId
    // get all IDs
    .getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
    // map to a UniqueZone (so zones with the same ZoneRules won't be duplicated)
    .map(zoneName -> new UniqueZone(ZoneId.of(zoneName)))
    // create Set
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This will create a `Set` with unique instances of `UniqueZone`, using the criteria defined in the `equals` method (if two `ZoneId` instances have the same `ZoneRules`, they are considered the same, and only one is inserted in the `Set`).

Now we just need to map this `Set` back to a `List`:

```
List<String> zoneList = uniqueZones.stream()
    // map back to the zoneId
    .map(u -> u.getZone().getId())
    // create list
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And now you can use the `zoneList` the same way you're already using.

---

With the code above, in JDK 1.8.0_144, the list has 385 elements, and only `Asia/Chungking` is on the list. As I'm using streams, you can't really predict which one of the three (`Asia/Chungking`, `Asia/Chongqing` or `Asia/Shanghai`) will be in the list.

If you want to have some control over it, you can explicity filter the names you don't want, by creating a list of names to be excluded. Suppose that I want to exclude `Asia/Chungking` and `Asia/Chongqing` (so only `Asia/Shanghai` will be in the list). I could do:

```
// zone names to be excluded
Set<String> excludedNames = new HashSet<>();
excludedNames.add("Asia/Chungking");
excludedNames.add("Asia/Chongqing");

Set<UniqueZone> uniqueZones = ZoneId
    // get all IDs
    .getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
    // filter names I don't want
    .filter(zoneName -> ! excludedNames.contains(zoneName))
    // map to a UniqueZone (so zones with the same ZoneRules won't be duplicated)
    .map(zoneName -> new UniqueZone(ZoneId.of(zoneName)))
    // create Set
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

With this, only `Asia/Shanghai` will be in the list.

**PS:** If this list of excluded names is long enough to cover all synonym cases, you don't even need the `UniqueZone` class (the filter will do all the job). But you'll need to previously know all the synonyms to be excluded.