# Unable to write new excel using Apache POI after removing duplicate rows

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am new to Apache POI.

I have written a small code for removing duplicate records from a excel file. I am successfully able to identify the duplicate records across sheets but when writing to a new file after removing records, no output is being generated.

Please help where I am goin wrong?

Am I writing properly ?? Or am missing something?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    HSSFWorkbook input_workbook;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook_Output_Final;

    HSSFSheet input_workbook_sheet;

    HSSFRow row_Output;
    HSSFRow row_1_index;
    HSSFRow row_2_index;

    String value1 = "";
    String value2 = "";
    int count;


    //main try catch block starts
    try {

        FileInputStream input_file = new FileInputStream("E:\\TEST\\Output.xls"); //reading from input file
        input_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(input_file));

        for (int sheetnum = 0; sheetnum < input_workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetnum++) { //traversing  sheets

            input_workbook_sheet = input_workbook.getSheetAt(sheetnum);

            int input_workbook_sheet_total_row = input_workbook_sheet.getLastRowNum(); //fetching last row nmber

            for (int input_workbook_sheet_row_1 = 0; input_workbook_sheet_row_1 <= input_workbook_sheet_total_row; input_workbook_sheet_row_1++) { //traversing row 1

                for (int input_workbook_sheet_row_2 = 0; input_workbook_sheet_row_2 <= input_workbook_sheet_total_row; input_workbook_sheet_row_2++) {

                    row_1_index = input_workbook_sheet.getRow(input_workbook_sheet_row_1);    //fetching one iteration row index
                    row_2_index = input_workbook_sheet.getRow(input_workbook_sheet_row_2);    //fetching sec iteration row index

                    if (row_1_index != row_2_index) {
                        count = 0;
                        value1 = "";
                        value2 = "";
                        for (int row_1_index_cell = 0; row_1_index_cell < row_1_index.getLastCellNum(); row_1_index_cell++)  { //traversing cell for each row
                            try {
                                value1 = value1 + formatter.formatCellValue(row_1_index.getCell(row_1_index_cell)); //fetching  row cells value
                                value2 = value2 + formatter.formatCellValue(row_2_index.getCell(row_1_index_cell)); //fetching row cells value 

                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            }
                            count++;
                            if (count == row_1_index.getLastCellNum()) {

                                if (value1.hashCode() == value2.hashCode()) { //remove the duplicate logic  
                                    System.out.println("deleted : " + row_2_index);
                                    System.out.println("------------------");
                                    input_workbook_sheet.removeRow(row_2_index);
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("E:\\TEST\\workbook.xls");
        input_workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        input_file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //main try catch block ends

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

1. you swallow any kind of Exception; Igotsome nullpointers with my test data, and that would prevent the workbook from being written
2. when removing rows, it is an old trick to move backwards through the row numbers because then you don't have to adjust for the row number you have just removed
3. the code empties the row, but it doesn't move all rows upwards (=there is a gap after the delete). If you want to remove that gap, you can work with shiftRows
4. you compare things by hashcode, which is possible (in some use cases), but I feel like .equals() is what you want to do. See also [Relationship between hashCode and equals method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java)

Here's some code that worked for my test data, feel free to comment if something doesn't work with your data:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    HSSFWorkbook input_workbook;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook_Output_Final;

    HSSFSheet input_workbook_sheet;

    HSSFRow row_Output;
    HSSFRow row_1_index;
    HSSFRow row_2_index;

    String value1 = "";
    String value2 = "";
    int count;

    FileInputStream input_file = new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\test.xls");
    input_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(input_file));

    for (int sheetnum = 0; sheetnum < input_workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetnum++) {

        input_workbook_sheet = input_workbook.getSheetAt(sheetnum);

        int input_workbook_sheet_total_row = input_workbook_sheet.getLastRowNum(); 

        for (int input_workbook_sheet_row_1 = input_workbook_sheet_total_row; input_workbook_sheet_row_1 >=0; input_workbook_sheet_row_1--) { // traversing

            for (int input_workbook_sheet_row_2 = input_workbook_sheet_total_row; input_workbook_sheet_row_2 >= 0 ; input_workbook_sheet_row_2--) {

                row_1_index = input_workbook_sheet.getRow(input_workbook_sheet_row_1);
                row_2_index = input_workbook_sheet.getRow(input_workbook_sheet_row_2); 

                if (row_1_index != null && row_2_index != null && row_1_index != row_2_index) {
                    count = 0;
                    value1 = "";
                    value2 = "";

                    int row_1_max = row_1_index.getLastCellNum() - 1;
                    for (int row_1_index_cell = 0; row_1_index_cell < row_1_max; row_1_index_cell++) {
                        try {
                            value1 = value1 + formatter.formatCellValue(row_1_index.getCell(row_1_index_cell)); 

                            value2 = value2 + formatter.formatCellValue(row_2_index.getCell(row_1_index_cell)); 

                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        count++;

                        if (value1.equals(value2)) {
                            System.out.println("deleted : " + row_2_index.getRowNum());
                            System.out.println("------------------");
                            input_workbook_sheet.removeRow(row_2_index);


                            input_workbook_sheet.shiftRows(
                                    row_2_index.getRowNum() + 1, 
                                    input_workbook_sheet_total_row, 
                                    -1, 
                                    true, 
                                    true);
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\workbook.xls");
    input_workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    input_file.close();
    input_workbook.close();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the pointers. :)
few points i would like to mention:

1.your code is removing all the duplicate rows unlike mine which is keeping only one of the duplicates, removing the rest. Maybe I wasn't clear about removing duplicates, sorry for that.

2. like you said removing the duplicates is making rows blank but not removing them.

3. why wouldn't be hash compare better approach than equal ?

Comment: I have added the shiftRows and a link to a deeper explanation of hashcode/equals. About 1: actually it should keep one line (the last one).It works with my test data, but if it doesn't work for you, I would need more information aboutthe data youcompare.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I was able to modify my code and made it work.:)