# Java hashset not removing node that it contains

Tags: java, hashset

I'm having an issue where the item that I'm trying to remove is in my HashSet, but both `contains()` and `remove()` return false. However, if I write a simple for loop:

```
HashSet<Node> myList;
myList.add(new Node("node"));    
Node myNode = new Node("node");
for (Node n : myList){
    if (n.equals(myNode)) System.out.println("Found Node in List");
}
```

I get the output as expected. If I switch for `myNode.equals(n)`, it works (equals is symmetrical).

I use my equals method (written for Node) successfully elsewhere, so I know that it works.

Does HashSet use the pointer, or possibly some other parameter of the object to compare? Despite not wanting duplicates, would I be better off using an arrayList and manually checking that I'm not adding a duplicate?

Comment: Have you overridden hashcode() also? Post the code of your Node class.

Comment: @AmitBera No, I was not aware that I had to, I don't have much experience with hashsets. That solved the problem

Comment: There is a contract between hashcode and equals.  You need to implement both in a correct way. Go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java.

Comment: Can you please post your Node class so that we can exactly identify what is the problem.

Comment: The problem is that I hadn't overridden hashcode(). With it correctly written, the problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown enough code, but I'm willing to bet that you have an incorrect `hashCode()` implementation in `Node`.