# How to remove oldest Student object from TreeSet?

Tags: java, collections

I'm trying to remove oldest Student from my TreeSet but the object is not getting deleted. Can someone please explain how to remove the oldest Student object from my TreeSet ?

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    private String studentId;
    private String studentAge;

    public Student(String studentId, String studentAge) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentAge = studentAge;
    }

    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentAge() {
        return studentAge;
    }

    public void setStudentAge(String studentAge) {
        this.studentAge = studentAge;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        if (Double.valueOf(studentAge).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o.getStudentAge())) == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else
            return Double.valueOf(studentAge).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o.getStudentAge()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Student student = (Student) obj;
        return (student.getStudentId().equals(studentId) && student.getStudentAge().equals(studentAge));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StudentId " + studentId + " Student Age " + studentAge;
    }

}


import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Student> studentList = new TreeSet<Student>();
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "5"));
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "15"));
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "25"));
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "3"));
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "2"));
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "1"));
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "10"));
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "6"));
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "7"));
        studentList.add(new Student("10001", "2"));

        System.out.println(studentList.last().getStudentAge());
        System.out.println(studentList);
        Student maxAge = studentList.last();
        System.out.println(studentList.remove(new Student(maxAge.getStudentId(), maxAge.getStudentAge())));
        System.out.println(studentList);

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your `hashCode` method?

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't return `1` if the `compareTo` returns `0` - you should return whatever `compareTo()` returns. Secondly, you should check for invalid age strings (e.g. `null` values), and maybe assume that they are `0`, depending on whatever you think makes more sense.

Comment: Why are you storing the age as a string? If you need it as a number, store it as a number.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Why would I need a hashcode for TreeSet?

Comment: @Jai I wanted a TreeSet with duplicates. Thats the reason why I was returning 1 when age is equal.

Comment: *Why would I need a hashcode* see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Your compare method is simply spoken plain wrong.

A first naive fix: extract the two ages values as number (and use integer, as age seems to always come as whole number). And then call

```
return Integer.compare(first, second);
```

only. ( maybe you will have to turn around the two values, depending how you want your set to be sorted )

Your current approach of returning 1 when the values are equal is just bogus.

The point is: the TreeSet can't properly sort the elements because your `compareTo()` method is logically broken. As soon as sort is working, you can easily identify the first or last element in the set and remove that one.

But the real issue here is: your underlying *design* is wrong. You see, when you have `equals()` and `compareTo()` people quickly talk about: should all equal efforts give 0 for `compareTo()`? This boils down to: what data goes into your `equals()` method. Think about it: does age the matter for the *identity* of two persons. No. You have a student **ID**. The *nature* of IDs is to uniquely *identify* things. So: you should really first clarify what makes up "unique" Students.

My suggestions:

- only the ID should be used, to uniquely identify Students. You can **not** have two students with the same student. You can not have two student objects with the same ID but different age. Because the ID **is** the student.
- from there, I would **drop** the Comparable interface from Student, and instead implement standalone `Comparator<Student>` instances. You could have one comparator that compares two Students to ascending age. And *another* one with descending.

That is the key point: you only use Comparable when you have a true "natural" sorting order, like for Integer. But persons, students: it depends on  context *how* to sort them. Maybe ascending on age. But maybe you add a *name* later, and then you want to sort these name strings.

Comment: To be consistent with equals, you also need to compare the student IDs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I wanted my TreeSet to have duplicates. Thats the reason why I was returning 1 in compareTo method.

Comment: @AndyTurner When you think about it: to be consistent, we have to drop Comparable. It is inconsistent by nature to have an **ID** field and then think that age or other properties *also* come into play for equality. So: thanks for your input, I enhanced m question accordingly.

Comment: @srujanrone I reworded my answer, to get to the real issues. Please have a look. And just for the record: dont forget about accepting an answer at some point ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, your `compareTo` method is wrong. You should never return `1` when two instances are equal. This is a trivial fix. Having said that, your `compareTo` method is wrong not only because of this, but also because you are comparing students **based only on their age**. `TreeSet` is a `Set`, and **sets can't have duplicate elements**, so this means that **your set won't be able to hold students that have the same age**.

Luckily, each student has a unique ID, so you could use this id to break ties (i.e. when two students have the same age), thus making two instances *different* as per the `compareTo` method, even if they have the same age:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    int result = Integer.compare(studentAge, o.getStudentAge());
    return result == 0 ? studentId.compareTo(o.getStudentId()) : result;
}
```

Note: this assumes the age is of type `int`.

Now, once you've fixed the `compareTo` method, you can use `TreeSet`'s lookup methods safely. To remove the oldest student from your `TreeSet`, you can use the [`pollLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#pollLast--) method, which does exactly what you want:

```
Student oldest = studentList.pollLast();
```

Answer (score 1):

Few observations, if corrected will solve the issue.

-- Why you have age as String ? Please make it an Integer or Double. In that case your compareTo method will be

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return this.studentAge.compareTo(o.getStudentAge());
}
```

-- If you still want to use the age as String use the below compareTo method.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return Double.valueOf(studentAge).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o.getStudentAge()));
}
```

Either of this will solve your problem.

---

Now the explanation: 
    Unlike other maps(since sets are internally maps only, hope you know that), the keys are not compared based on equals method. The keys are compared based on compareTo if Comparable is implemented, or Compartor implementation.
Since you compareTo method is buggy, the Student with age 25 is never found when the remove method was called.

When the remove method is called, it tries to search the key using the age, but since your compare technically never returns 0 (which means equal), so the object is never found hence never deleted.

But the last method gives the correct student value, because, the compareTo method in case of populating the values will work correctly..

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion,the `equals` method should consider the following conditions while overriding for .

1. If both the objects are pointing to same reference then they are equal by default, there is no need for content comparison
2. It should handle the ClassCastException and NullPointerException at run time, you can achieve this with `instanceof` operator.

added `String` class `equals` method for reference

```
  public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```