# Function to group equivalent elements of an array

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

Is there a *javascript* or *coffeescript* function (or maybe an extension of the *underscore* **groupBy** function) that receives as parameters an **array** and an **equivalence comparator** (a boolean function with TWO arguments, not just ONE argument) and **groups the array elements** based on this equivalence comparator?

As an example of what I want:

```
areEquivalent = (p1, p2) ->
  p1.birthYear == p2.birthYear and
  p1.birthPlace == p2.birthPlace and
  p1.gender == p2.gender

p1 = {name:'Anna', birthYear: 1990, birthPlace: 'Alaska', gender: 'female', hasCar: true, hasChildren: false}
p2 = {name:'John', birthYear: 1990, birthPlace: 'Alaska', gender: 'male', hasCar: true, hasChildren: false}
p3 = {name:'Dora', birthYear: 1980, birthPlace: 'Hawaii', gender: 'female', hasCar: true, hasChildren: true}
p4 = {name:'Lumi', birthYear: 1980, birthPlace: 'Hawaii', gender: 'female', hasCar: false, hasChildren: false}
p5 = {name:'Jack', birthYear: 1990, birthPlace: 'Alaska', gender: 'male', hasCar: false, hasChildren: false}

console.log areEquivalent p1, p2
# false
console.log areEquivalent p3, p4
# true

people = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]

console.log _.groupEquivalentObjects(people, areEquivalent)
# [ [p1], [p2,p5], [p3,p4] ]
```

Comment: Can you extend the equivalence function to a comparison function and use a sort? (It doesn't matter what order the comparison function produces, as long as it's self-consistent.)

Comment: Also, you know this'll run in time quadratic in the number of equivalence classes, right? It'd be much faster if you could somehow produce an identity code for each equivalence class and use `groupBy`.

Comment: Please don't put tags in titles, that's what tags are for.

Comment: What I put in the title were not meant as tags, but they were alternative choices for the implementation :) (meaning that I was searching for an implementation in either/some of coffeescript or javascript or underscore)

Comment: Not getting this question--underscore's `groupBy` **already** takes a function. "Splits a collection into sets, grouped by the result of running each value through iterator." Did you read its documentation?

Comment: @torazaburo: Yes, I am aware of Underscore's groupBy function. But it takes a function with only ONE argument - the currently iterated item in the collection. What I need is a version with TWO arguments: pairs of the items in the collection. And yes, I am aware that this can be O(NxN), but that's not important in this case.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194846/is-there-any-kind-of-hashcode-function-in-javascript. `JSON.stringify` might work.

Answer (score 4):

Can you not just pass `_.groupBy()` and expression which will differentiate your inputs properly?

```
p1 = {name:'Anna', birthYear: 1990, birthPlace: 'Alaska', gender: 'female', hasCar: true, hasChildren: false}
p2 = {name:'John', birthYear: 1990, birthPlace: 'Alaska', gender: 'male', hasCar: true, hasChildren: false}
p3 = {name:'Dora', birthYear: 1980, birthPlace: 'Hawaii', gender: 'female', hasCar: true, hasChildren: true}
p4 = {name:'Lumi', birthYear: 1980, birthPlace: 'Hawaii', gender: 'female', hasCar: false, hasChildren: false}
p5 = {name:'Jack', birthYear: 1990, birthPlace: 'Alaska', gender: 'male', hasCar: false, hasChildren: false}

people = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]

groups = _.groupBy(people, (x) -> '' + x.birthYear + x.birthPlace + x.gender)

console.log groups
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vKz6r/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers and suggestions.

For the moment I implemented this not-very-optimal solution:

```
# Modifies the received array, by removing all the elements equivalent to the first one,
# and returning them in a separate array
extractAllObjectsEquivalentToFirst = (array, areEquivalent) ->
  return [] if array.length == 0
  first = array.shift()
  equivalent = [first]
  different = []
  while array.length > 0
    elem = array.shift()
    if areEquivalent(elem,first)
      equivalent.push elem
    else
      different.push elem
  array[..] = different
  return equivalent

groupEquivalentObjects = (array, areEquivalent) ->
  arrayClone = array[..]
  groups = []
  previous = arrayClone.length
  while arrayClone.length > 0
    groups.push extractAllObjectsEquivalentToFirst(arrayClone, areEquivalent)
    if arrayClone.length >= previous
      console.warn "Array length did not decrease!"
      arrayClone = []
    previous = arrayClone.length
  return groups
```

But indeed a better solution would be to define *some kind of **hashCode()** function* for the items, and pass that function as a parameter to **_.groupBy()**

In my current use case, some of the object properties that I need to **compare** are actually **arrays**, for which I need to use **_.isEqual()** inside the equivalence comparator.

And for the moment I'm too lazy to think of a way to define a "hashCode" function that would ensure the unequivocal equivalence of values for my use case.