# I have to Hash a text with HMAC sha256 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to Hash a text using HMAC SHA-256 in Javascript 
I have [secret Ket]

I have Ruby code to hash, but I need Javascript code to Hash the text

Ruby Code

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(
  'sha256', # hash function
  'HFgGgIOaLiyFgUhIjirOoqxloHuiLNr20jkhXrNw', # secret key (keep safe!)
  current_user.email # user's email address
)
```

Please suggest me for any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any SHA-256 javascript implementations that are generally considered trustworthy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338890/are-there-any-sha-256-javascript-implementations-that-are-generally-considered-t)

Comment: browser or server side?

Answer (score 16):

With the [Web crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) native api, taken from [this source](https://github.com/danharper/hmac-examples):

```js
async function HMAC(key, message){
  const g = str => new Uint8Array([...unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))),
  k = g(key),
  m = g(message),
  c = await crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', k, { name: 'HMAC', hash: 'SHA-256' },true, ['sign']),
  s = await crypto.subtle.sign('HMAC', c, m);
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(s)))
}

/* TEST */
HMAC("mypassword", "Hello world!")
 .then(e => console.log(e))
 // jhg4cIbXnNicUx6BeG9EKEQHLp6NuBVzBp1d5D1Ghw4=
```

Comment: This is really helpful! No external dependencies, just a tiny function to take care of it - thanks a lot man!

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  I changed your function g() to use the TextEncoder.  
  const encoder = new TextEncoder()
  const messageBytes = encoder.encode(message)

Comment: why is the js output different from the nodejs output?

Comment: Doesn't work, For instance try with message='a' and key='b'. This outputs 'y0SLRAxCrIrQhPyKh5XJj1t4AjWcMF6r1X7Nsg4kiJY=' instead of cb448b440c42ac8ad084fc8a8795c98f5b7802359c305eabd57ecdb20e248896

Answer (score 5):

From [@KVM's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081874/i-have-to-hash-a-text-with-hmac-sha256-in-javascript#comment127351980_56416039) on [@NVRM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56416039/3673659), their approach returns the hash in Base64 format, instead of HEX.

Moreover, they use [a "non-native" approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers) for converting a `String` to an `ArrayBuffer` (which may have limitations).

A better approach would be with the native Web API [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder). I've created an alternative method that uses `TextEncoder` and returns the value in hex instead Base64.

```js
async function hmac(secretKey, message, algorithm = "SHA-256") {
    // Convert the message and secretKey to Uint8Array
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const messageUint8Array = encoder.encode(message);
    const keyUint8Array = encoder.encode(secretKey);

    // Import the secretKey as a CryptoKey
    const cryptoKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        keyUint8Array,
        { name: "HMAC", hash: algorithm },
        false,
        ["sign"]
    );

    // Sign the message with HMAC and the CryptoKey
    const signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
        "HMAC",
        cryptoKey,
        messageUint8Array
    );

    // Convert the signature ArrayBuffer to a hex string
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(signature));
    const hashHex = hashArray
        .map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
        .join("");

    return hashHex;
}

// Example
const mySecretKey = "b";
const myMessage = "a";
hmac(mySecretKey, myMessage).then(h=>console.log(h)); // cb448b440c42ac8ad084fc8a8795c98f5b7802359c305eabd57ecdb20e248896
```

Comment: Anyone landing on this page looking for a JavaScript solution to Paddle Billing verification, this is the answer, look no further! Thanks @Advena!

Answer (score 4):

I think CryptoJS would be able to do it using

`CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(current_user.email, 'HFgGgIOaLiyFgUhIjirOoqxloHuiLNr20jkhXrNw')
  .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)`

Comment: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

Comment: The [README.md](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/README.md) file in that repository now says the library is no longer supported. The note has been added four months ago.