# Signing JWT - do I do it wrong?

Tags: javascript, jwt

I'm trying to make a JWT generator in JavaScript for educational purposes. There is a [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) tool to create and/or validate JWT.

I'm struggling to get my results match the results from the validator. The problem is the signature.

Here's my code:

```
function base64url(input) {
    return btoa(typeof input === 'string' ? input : JSON.stringify(input))
        .replace(/=+$/, '')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_');
}

const JWT = {
    encode(header, payload, secret) {
        const unsigned = [base64url(header), base64url(payload)].join('.');

        return [unsigned, base64url(sha256.hmac(secret, unsigned))].join('.');
    }
};
```

To encrypt HMAC SHA256 I'm using [js-sha256](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha256) library with `sha256.hmac(key, value)` prototype. I compared it with online tools and it works fine.

Now, I test it with the following code:

```
const jwt = JWT.encode(
    {
        alg: 'HS256',
        typ: 'JWT'
    },
    123,
    'xxx'
);
```

The result I get is:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.MTIz.NzhlNTFmYzUxOGQ2YjNlZDFiOTM0ZGRhOTUwNDFmMzEwMzdlNmZkZWRhNGFlMjdlNDU3ZTZhNWRhYjQ1YzFiMQ

On the other hand, the result from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) is:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.MTIz.eOUfxRjWs-0bk03alQQfMQN-b97aSuJ-RX5qXatFwbE

As you can see, the two out of three chunks of JWT are identical in my result and [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) result. The signature is different and if you ask me, the signature generated by it is surprisingly short. That tool also marks my own JWT as invalid.

I checked with online HMAC SHA256 generators and it looks like my code creates a valid signature, so:

```
base64url(sha256.hmac('xxx', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.MTIz')) ===
'NzhlNTFmYzUxOGQ2YjNlZDFiOTM0ZGRhOTUwNDFmMzEwMzdlNmZkZWRhNGFlMjdlNDU3ZTZhNWRhYjQ1YzFiMQ'
```

Is [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) just broken or does it do it some other way?

Comment: I want to know also. It happen only symmetric type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't say you're doing it wrong, but you missed a small but important detail.
The result from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) is correct and the **hash** you calculate is also correct. But the **signature** you create with your hash is not correct.

The hash you calculate with `sha256.hmac(secret, unsigned)` is a large number but the return value of the function is a hexadecimal string representation of that large number. For the signature you need to base64url encode the original number instead of it's string representation.

I modified your code, so that it encodes the hash value directly to base64url (node.js version):

```
const JWT = {
    encode(header, payload, secret) {
        const unsigned = [base64url(header), base64url(payload)].join('.');
        const hash  = sha256.hmac(secret, unsigned);
        console.log(hash);        
        var signature = new Buffer.from(hash, 'hex').toString('base64').replace(/\+/g,'-').replace(/\=+$/m,'');

        return [unsigned, signature].join('.');
    }
};
```

or, if you don't use node.js, you can use this instead (as suggested by Robo Robok):

```
const JWT = {
    encode(header, payload, secret) {
        const unsigned = [base64url(header), base64url(payload)].join('.');

        return [unsigned, base64url(sha256.hmac(secret, unsigned).replace(/\w{2}/g, byte => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byte, 16))))].join('.');
    }
};
```

The result is a token, which is identical to the one created with [jwt.io](https://jwt.io):

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.MTIz.eOUfxRjWs-0bk03alQQfMQN-b97aSuJ-RX5qXatFwbE

See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121763/how-to-manually-validate-a-jwt-signature-using-online-tools/50153299#50153299), in which I explained the steps to compare the results from different tools.

Answer (score 0):

Using information from this page and the [JWT specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519), here is a working JWT browser implementation.

The [HMAC function is taken here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081874/i-have-to-hash-a-text-with-hmac-sha256-in-javascript/56416039#56416039), and all that is combined into an `async` mechanism.

---

Expected output for this question:

```
// Expected JWT
// eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.MTIz.eOUfxRjWs-0bk03alQQfMQN-b97aSuJ-RX5qXatFwbE`
{
    alg: 'HS256',
    typ: 'JWT'
},
123,
'xxx'
```

---

The second example uses the data from the example provided at https://jwt.io/.

```
// Expected JWT
// eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
},
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
},
'your-256-bit-secret'
```

---

```js
const JWT = async (header, payload, secret) => {
    const unsigned = [base64url(header), base64url(payload)].join('.');
    let JWT;
    await hmac(secret, unsigned)
      .then((h) => {
        JWT = [unsigned, base64url(h.replace(/\w{2}/g, byte => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byte, 16))))].join('.');
    })
    return JWT;
}

const base64url = (input) => btoa(typeof input === 'string' ? input : JSON.stringify(input))
        .replace(/=+$/, '')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_');

const hmac = async (secretKey, message, algorithm = "SHA-256") => {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const messageUint8Array = encoder.encode(message);
    const keyUint8Array = encoder.encode(secretKey);
    const cryptoKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        keyUint8Array,
        { name: "HMAC", hash: algorithm },
        false,
        ["sign"]
    );
    const signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
        "HMAC",
        cryptoKey,
        messageUint8Array
    );
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(signature));
    const hashHex = hashArray
      .map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
      .join("");
    return hashHex;
}

/* TEST */
// Expected output
// eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.MTIz.eOUfxRjWs-0bk03alQQfMQN-b97aSuJ-RX5qXatFwbE
JWT(
    {
        alg: 'HS256',
        typ: 'JWT'
    },
    123,
    'xxx'
).then(jwt => console.log(jwt));

// As the demo in jwt.io
// Expected output
// eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
JWT(
    {
      "alg": "HS256",
      "typ": "JWT"
    },
    {
      "sub": "1234567890",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "iat": 1516239022
    },
    'your-256-bit-secret'
).then(jwt => console.log(jwt));
```

[image]