# How to handle nested refrence passed to a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have some objects:

```
var a = {
   toString: () => 'a'
}
var b = {
   toString: () => 'b'
}

function someFunc(...params) {
    params.forEach((p)=>{
        console.log(p);   //consoles - {toString: ƒ toString()} for both objects
   })
 }

someFunc(a,b);
```

I want to pass these objects to some functions like memoize function, isEqual function, deepCopy function etc. I don't want to use any third party library such as lodash. I want to understand how do we **differentiate** between these objects inside `someFunc`?
I have tried : `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` but this doesn't work in case of objects having functions.
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-waterfall-4fsqd8?file=/src/index.js)

Edit:
I have tried Implementing the object refrence method.

```
function someFunc() {
  let cache = {};
  return function (...params) {
    var ObjectReference = [];
    let set = {};
    params.forEach((p) => {
      ObjectReference.push(p);
      set["ObjectReference." + ObjectReference.indexOf(p)+p] =     true;
    });
    let key = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(set))
    console.log(key);
    if (cache[key]) {
      console.log("cached");
    } else {
      cache[key] = true;
      console.log("Not cached");
        }
     };
  }

mem(a, b); //not cached
mem(b, a);  //cached - should be **not cached**
```

`console.log(key);` gives:

1. {ObjectReference.0a: true, ObjectReference.1b: true}
2. {ObjectReference.0b: true, ObjectReference.1a: true}
   As we can see the two objects are different. I'm unable to understand why it goes inside cached block?

Edit 2 : The above is happening because the key is getting set as `[object object]`. To avoid this I tried using Map and WeakMap but they are failing for

```
    mem(a, b); //not cached
    mem(a, b); // not cached
```

Comment: You need to use recursion to deep check if all the key values are the same or not.

Comment: You can just add a unique ID to each object.

Comment: @Reyno Not an option.

Comment: Differentiate how? `a === b` will give you `false`. Is that enough? If not, then what's the problem?

Comment: @mgm793 How will you check nested function recursively?

Comment: A function its an object in js so you can check the key values of it

Comment: @VLAZ What if I want to make unique key out of a,b. And cache those keys.

Comment: So, something like this? [Is there hash code function accepting any object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194846)

Comment: @VLAZ I think it works. I'll try for some edge cases and let you know.