# JavaScript/Firebase: How to store an URL in Firebase realtime DB?

Tags: javascript, url, firebase-realtime-database, symbols

I am simply trying to store some data in my firebase realtime database, but when doing so I keep getting this error:

**`Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`**

The problem isn’t the data I want to store, but the name I want to give the path. I want the path-name to be an URL. But it obviously contains those "illegal" symbols.

This is how I try to name the path and store some data:

```
// URL example: 
var newNote = firebase
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child("/https://developer.mozilla.org/en
 US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings") // <-- this is the problem
  .set({
    title: title,
    icon: icon,
    body: body,
    url: url,
  });
```

**Any ideas on how to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to encode the URL so that it no longer contains any illegal characters. Since you also store the URL *inside* the node, you can get away with a one-way encoding for the key.

So for example, you could *remove* all illegal characters from the string. Assuming you don't want the database to interpret the `/` in the key, you'd also remove those, and end up with:

```
.child("/httpsdevelopermozillaorgen USdocsLearnJavaScriptFirst_stepsStrings")
```

Now whenever you get a URL in your code again, you apply the same encoding and end up with the same key.

There are **many** such encoding schemes, and you should pick what fits best for your use-case. For example, you could also replace the illegal characters with something, to result in a more readable key:

```
.child("/https___developer_mozilla_org_en US_docs_Learn_JavaScript_First_steps_Strings")
```

Or you could completely forego readability, and use a [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194846/is-there-hash-code-function-accepting-any-object-type) of the URL as its key:

```
.child(hashCode("/https://developer.mozilla.org/en US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings"))
```

Which would (with the `hashCode` function I linked) end up storing in:

```
.child("-1097737053")
```